# How to refactor js typeahead instantiation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, refactoring, typeahead.js

I have the following code block instantiating typeahead

```
$("#searchbox").typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
  }, {
    name: "Type0",
    displayKey: "name",
    source: bloodHound[0].ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
      header: "<h4 class='typeahead-header'><img src='Type0.png'>Type0</h4>",
      suggestion: Handlebars.compile(["{{name}}<br><small>{{address}}        </small>"].join(""))
    }
  }, {
    name: "Type1",
    displayKey: "name",
    source: bloodHound[1].ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
      header: "<h4 class='typeahead-header'><img src='Type1.png'>Type1</h4>",
      suggestion: Handlebars.compile(["{{name}}<br><small>{{address}}</small>"].join(""))
    }
  }
)
```

If I want to add another Type e.g. Type2 I have to copy and paste the block therefore not efficient. I have the types available in an array called types.

How would I have one block of code that loops the array and creates the same as result as above. All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your `types` array is supposed to look like, but here is how I would set it up:

```js
var types = [
  {
    name: 'Type0',
    displayKey: 'Type 0'
  },
  {
    name: 'Type1',
    displayKey: 'Type 1'
  }
]


var args = types.map(function (type, i) {
  return {
    name: type.name,
    displayKey: type.displayKey,
    source: bloodHound[i].ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
      header: '<h4 class="typeahead-header"><img src="' + type.name + '.png">' + type.name + '</h4>',
      suggestion: Handlebars.compile(["{{name}}<br><small>{{address}}        </small>"].join(""))
    }
  }
})

args.unshift({ minLength: 3 })

// Calls typeahead with a variable number of arguments on the search box
$.fn.typeahead.apply($("#searchbox"), args)
```